# Lodash double where

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a JS array with the following structure:

```
[
{group: 'group1', addons: [{name: 'addon1', price: '100'}, {name: 'addon2', price: '130'}] },
{group: 'group2', addons: [{name: 'addon3', price: '150'}] },
{group: 'group3', addons: [{name: 'addon4', price: '200'}] }
]
```

So it's an array of groups, each containing an array of `addons`.

How do I implement a `getAddon(addonName)` method with the help of [lodash](https://lodash.com/)? It's very simple to do with 2 for/foreach loops, but maybe there is a simpler way?

For example `getAddon('addon1')` should return `{name: 'addon1', price: '100'}` - first found add-on entry.

How I implemented it, sorry for typescript code:

```
public getAddon(addonName: string): _IAddonModel {

            if (!this.groups) return null;

            //todo refactor using underscore/lodash
            for (var i = 0; i < this.groups.length; i++) {
                var group = this.groups[i];

                for (var j = 0; j < group.addons.length; j++) {
                    var addon = group.addons[j];

                    if (addon && addon.name === addonName) {
                        return addon;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = _(data)
    .pluck('addons')
    .flatten()
    .findWhere({name: 'addon3'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4g4wbu13/1/

So you - [pluck()](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) all the nested `addons` arrays, [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) them in a single level depth array, and use [findWhere()](https://lodash.com/docs#findWhere) to get the specific item.